# how to use excel vba to Opening a .csv and saving it as .xlsx

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access form to open an .csv file using choose file.

```
Private Sub Import_Click()
Dim ExcelApp
Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open (Me.txtCSVFIle.Value)

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Me.txtCSVFIle.Value, FileFormat:=51
ExcelApp.Visible = False

ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.close False
ExcelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

the value of Me.txtCSVFIle.Value would be "I:\csv files\20140228_ExtStats.csv"

Now the problem is my save as command is saving it as it's name with .csv. How can i remove the .csv so that my next statement FileFormat:=51 make it save to .xlsx?

*Ps: the Displayalerts is set to false to prevent user to be confuse.

Expected result should be save as "I:\csv files\20140228_ExtStats.xlsx".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Import_Click()
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With ExcelApp
        .Workbooks.Open (Me.txtCSVFIle.Value)            
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(Me.txtCSVFIle.Value, InStrRev(Me.txtCSVFIle.Value, ".") - 1), FileFormat:=51
        .Visible = False            
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(myfile.Value, InStrRev(myfile.Value, ".") - 1), FileFormat:=51

Comment: I activate variable     myfile here and need to pick only the name of the csv file and save as ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Left(myfile.Value, InStrRev(myfile.Value, ".") - 1), FileFormat:=51